# Array syntax with XSD generated code

Tags: c#, xsd.exe

I have generated a class from XSD.  The following

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("mailer", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public itemOrderMailer[] mailer {
    get {
        return this.mailerField;
    }
    set {
        this.mailerField = value;
    }
}
```

Does not allow me to use syntax

```
itemOrder order = new itemOrder();
            order.mailer = {};
```

I get error "; expected" from the compiler.

There's no issue doing

> int[] ints = { };

Why?  Aren't these both arrays?

Comment: order.mailer = new itemOrderMailer[] {};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working with the ints only, because you have declaration and initialization in the same line.
Try this:

```
int[] ints;
ints = { };
```

it isn't working.

This however is:

```
int[] ints;
ints = new int[]{ };
```

But it really doesn't make a lot of sense, because you just created an array with 0 elements in it. Not very useful...

Anyway, to make your code work with the mailer, use this:

```
itemOrder order = new itemOrder();
order.mailer = new itemOrderMailer[]{};
```

Comment: I know the 0 element array looks silly.  I'm actually using JSON syntax, but took that out of the question cause it isn't relevant to the problem.  Great answer thanks!